# Importing 10 billion rows into mysql

Tags: mysql, database, large-files

I have a .csv file with 10 billion rows.  I want to check that each row is unique.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I was thinking perhaps importing to mysql would allow me to find out uniqueness quickly.  How can I upload this huge file to mysql?  I have already tried row-by-row insert statements and also the 'LOAD DATA INFILE' command but both failed.

Thanks

Comment: was there an error that caused them to fail?

Comment: Is MySQL really designed to deal with 10 billion rows? Most databases require some serious tweaks with placement of indexes, db files, memory, etc. to manage a table that large.

Comment: Does each row have a field that should act as a unique key, or do you need to compare the entire row?

Comment: @Thomas The Insert row by row method 'failed' because it would have taken almost a year to populate the database.  The LOAD DATA INFILE method failed because the load data process ran over night and stopped without inserting a single row

Comment: @DNA  There is only one column per row in my .csv file. I will rely on mysql's auto-increment feature as my primary key.  The database will thus have 2 columns.

Comment: @Tucker - About how many characters is this column that is being imported?

Comment: @Thomas about 35 characters on average

Comment: @Tucker. Wow. Assuming a bigint PK, your table will be in the neighborhood of 480 GB in size when all is said and done. Whatever machine on which you load this thing isn't going to be a happy camper and even less happy when you try to run analyses against it.

Comment: @Thomas  Yes I know, that is why I'm asking for the best solution.  Perhaps mysql isn't the best database software for this task?

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?32,6855,6855#msg-6855 -- that was quite some time back, couldn't find any recent references about smashing through the MAXROWS limit.  The limit then was 2^32-1, far lesser than 10bn..

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use a database for this purpose, unless it needed to end up in the database eventually. Assuming you have the same formatting for each row (so that you don't have "8.230" and "8.23", or extra spaces on start/end of lines of equal values), use a few [textutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/textutils/textutils.html) included with most POSIX environments (Linux, Mac OS X), or available for Windows via [GnuWIn32 coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

Here is the sequence of steps to do from your system shell. First, sort the file (this step is required):

```
sort ten.csv > ten_sorted.csv
```

Then find unique rows from sorted data:

```
uniq ten_sorted.csv > ten_uniq.csv
```

Now you can check to see how many rows there are in the final file:

```
wc ten_uniq.csv
```

---

Or you can just use pipes for combining the three steps with one command line:

```
sort ten.csv | uniq | wc
```

Comment: I'm probably a bit late, but for such a huge data set it will be much faster to do this instead of sort and uniq separately: `LANG=C sort -u boop.csv` and additionally, the `--parallel` option can allow parallelization to massively improve performance (at the cost of memory).

Answer (score 1):

Does the data have a unique identifier? Have this column as primary key in your mysql table and when you go to import the data, mysql should throw an error if you have duplicates.

As for how to go about doing it..just read in the file row by row and do an insert on each row.

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing from Excel or such other programs.  See [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2345/import_csv_file_directly_into_mysql/) for how to cleanse the csv file before importing it into MySQL.  Regarding the unique row, as long as your table schema is right, MySQL should be able to take care of it.

EDIT:

Whether the source is Excel or not, [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](http://support.modwest.com/content/6/253/en/how-do-i-import-delimited-data-into-mysql.html) appears to be the way to go.

10bn rows, and LOAD DATA LOCAL gives you error?  Are you sure there is no problem with the csv file?

Comment: Excel with 10 billion rows available-which version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to truncate your database into separate small bite size chunks. Use Big Dump.

http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump.php

Answer (score 0):

If you do have 10 billion rows then you will struggle working with this data.

You would need to look at partitioning your database (ref here: [about mysql partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/performance-partitioning.html))

However, even with that large number you would be requiring some serious hardware to cut through the work involved there.

Also, what would you do if a row was found to be nonunique? Would you want to continue importing the data? If you import the data would you import the identical row or flag it as a duplicate? Would you stop processing.

Comment: I would like to load all the data into the database, and run some queries to check for uniqueness on subsets of the data.

Comment: if you have a MS SQL 2005 or later version available I would look into using SSIS you would be able to use the file import functionality within that to load the data into tables. I suggest you set a couple of indexes on the table for the columns you will be querying on before the import though.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of job linux is "made for".

First you have to split the file in to many smaller files:

```
split -l 100 filename
```

After this you have few options with the two commands sort / uniq, and after having timed 8 different options with a file of 1 million IP address from an ad exchange log-file, and found a almost 20x difference between using LC_ALL=C or not. For example:

```
LC_ALL=C sort IP_1m_rows.txt > temp_file
LC_ALL=C uniq temp_file > IP_unique_rows.txt

real    0m1.283s
user    0m1.121s
sys     0m0.088s
```

Where as the same without LC=ALL_C:

```
sort IP_1m_rows.txt > temp_file
uniq temp_file > IP_unique_rows.txt

real    0m24.596s
user    0m24.065s
sys     0m0.201s
```

Piping the command and using LC_ALL=C was 2x slower than the fastest:

```
LC_ALL=C sort IP_1m_rows.txt | uniq > IP_unique_rows.txt

real    0m3.532s
user    0m3.677s
sys     0m0.106s
```

Databases are not useful for one-off jobs like this, and flatfiles will get you surprisingly far even with more challenging / long-term objectives.

Comment: Could you try your test with `LANG=C` *instead* of `LC_ALL=C`? On my datasets it's about 2x as fast.